# Enumerating unique k-combinations from a multiset with known repetitions (finite multiplicities)

Tags: algorithm, math, logic, combinations, combinatorics

I'll start with a mental exercise I made up to make what I'm trying to do easier to explain and less obscure.

---

Say I know of a shop called ***FRUITS*** which has infinite quantities of every fruit currently known <sup>1</sup>.

Say that I got a machine that uses complex *combinatorial* logic to convert any set of M=4 items from ***FRUITS*** to an object not among the 4 I gave <sup>2</sup>.
I can test the type of output I would get by giving it 4 names as well without using up the fruits.

I ask a friend to go into ***FRUITS***, pick a total number of fruits >= ***M*** (with at least 2 types), and they'll give me the *name* and *count* for each fruit they chose (e.g. `{Apple: 1, Banana: 3, ... }` or `[Apple,Banana,...]` and `[1,3,...]`).

---

I want to create an efficient algorithm (any language can be used to illustrate) to *find all unique inputs* I could give my machine without needing to check all ***M***-combinations or to list out every single fruit (viz. in lexicographic order) using the pair of lists <sup>3</sup>.
I want to do this without recursion, as the lists could be fairly large <sup>4</sup>.

---

The function I currently have takes `names` as one list, and `counts` as another of the same length (say `N`)<sup>5</sup>. I'm hoping to have the final version output a list of `m` lists with their lengths being equal to the number of unique combinations (`m` =4 in my earlier analogy); these lists will hold indices to the `names`/`counts` lists (pseudocode to illustrate -- note the below return value 1-indexed):

```
function (names: [A,B,C], counts: [2,2,1], m = 4) {
   // ...
   return [
      [1,1,1],[1,2,1],[2,2,2],[2,3,3]
   ]
   // Transposed matrix form to clearly show the 3 combinations (substituted names for indices)
   //
   //   A A B B
   //   A B B C
   //   A A B C
}
```

(The reason I chose to return `m` lists is because `m` has a fair chance of being a constant later on)

This is actually part of a larger project I want to do involving combinatorial optimization -- i.e. the real goal would be to find the combinations needed to maximize/minimize the sum of a quantitative property shared by the items in the list (e.g. maximize Vitamin C). But I felt like that question by itself would be too broad or difficult, so I'm starting with off what I *think* is the first step.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> In this world, all fruits with the same name as exactly identical (e.g. any Apple is equivalent to another Apple).</sup> 
<sup><sup>2</sup> For simplicity, you can assume the output is not in FRUITS.</sup> 
<sup><sup>3</sup> Bonus points if a callback or block of code can be effectively integrated as combinations are found (e.g. to test with my fruit converter and create a map).</sup> 
<sup><sup>4</sup> I've actually have a recursive version working, but I'm hoping for a more efficient algorithm as it looks like I'll be working in Lua</sup>
<sup><sup>5</sup> Sanity checks aren't important here as input will be checked beforehand</sup>

Comment: @YenForYang Please add a concrete example of what the function input should be and what the output should be. Thanks!